# Is " to make some criminals to be punished " a valid construction?

Tags: sentence-construction

Can you help me to check this sentences,i am not sure if this sentence is right.

> I think we should use the prison to make some criminals be punished for the crimes that they have done.

Do you think "to make to be punished" is a valid way to say "to make them feel remorseful?"

Answer (score 2):

> I think we should use the prison to make some criminals **be punished** for the crimes that they have done.

No, the meaning will not be equal to "make them feel remorseful".

The meaning is equal to the meaning of this sentence, which uses an active form of the verb **punish** instead of the passive form:

> I think we should use the prison to **punish** some criminals for the crimes that they have done.

A criminal punished is not necessarily a remorseful criminal.

Furthermore, the combination "Make them be punished" sounds awkward, despite being formally grammatical.

One possible rephrase retaining the verb "make" is:

> I think we should use the prison to make some criminals **repent** (of/for) the crimes that they have done.